# I need help figuring out how to turn online data into a usable list that I can print data from

Tags: python

In a program I am working on, I use ArcCloud's music fingerprinting service. after uploading the data I need identified, I am given back this piece of data:

```
    re = ACRCloudRecognizer(config)
    data = (re.recognize_by_file('audio_name.mp3', 0))
```

```
>>>data

'{"metadata":{"timestamp_utc":"2020-05-18 23:00:59","music":[{"label":"NoCopyrightSounds","play_offset_ms":125620,"duration_ms":326609,"external_ids":{},"artists":[{"name":"Culture Code & Regoton"}],"result_from":1,"acrid":"a53ea40c6a8b4a6795ac3d799f6a4aec","title":"Waking Up","genres":[{"name":"Electro"}],"album":{"name":"Waking Up"},"score":100,"external_metadata":{},"release_date":"2014-05-25"}]},"cost_time":5.5099999904633,"status":{"msg":"Success","version":"1.0","code":0},"result_type":0}\n'
```

I think it's a list, but I am unable to figure out how to navigate nor grab specific information from it. I'm unsure how they set up the information, and what patterns to look for. Ideally, I would like to create a print function that would print the title, artists, and album.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: it looks like JSON to me. `data = json.loads(re.recognize_by_file('audio_name.mp3', 0))` should create a dict-like structure

Comment: @AdamSmith Thanks so much! I used the type() function to see that it created a string, and by using the json command i got a dictionary! I got the rest working, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Formatting the JSON makes it more legible

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "timestamp_utc": "2020-05-18 23:00:59",
    "music": [
      {
        "label": "NoCopyrightSounds",
        "play_offset_ms": 125620,
        "duration_ms": 326609,
        "external_ids": {},
        "artists": [
          {
            "name": "Culture Code & Regoton"
          }
        ],
        "result_from": 1,
        "acrid": "a53ea40c6a8b4a6795ac3d799f6a4aec",
        "title": "Waking Up",
        "genres": [
          {
            "name": "Electro"
          }
        ],
        "album": {
          "name": "Waking Up"
        },
        "score": 100,
        "external_metadata": {},
        "release_date": "2014-05-25"
      }
    ]
  },
  "cost_time": 5.5099999904633,
  "status": {
    "msg": "Success",
    "version": "1.0",
    "code": 0
  },
  "result_type": 0
}
```

Looks like you're looking for `.metadata.music.title` (presumably), but only if `.status.code` is 0